# How can I prevent Maven from checking for updates from repositories that I don't list in my settings.xml file?

Tags: java, maven-2

In my *settings.xml* file I have listed repositories that I want Maven to use (see the file below). These repositories are located in the build machine and I am working this way to prevent a build fail when there's is no Internet connection in the build machine.

The problem is that Maven automatically looks for updates in the central repository (and possibly from other non-listed repositories) during the build. Is there a way to prevent this behaviour?

```
 ...
<profile>
  <id>myProfile</id>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </snapshots>
      <id>myRepo</id>
      <url>file://${my.home}/maven/.m2/repository</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </snapshots>
      <id>myRepo</id>
      <url>file://${my.home}/maven/.m2/repository</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
</profile>
...
```

**Note:** Using the offline option (e.g. -o flag) is not an option for me. What I really want is Maven to use only the repositories that I list in my *settings.xml* file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every Maven project inherits the configuration for the central repository from the [Maven Super POM](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html). You can use Maven's mirrors feature to redirect calls to central to your preferred repository. You do this by adding some configuration to your settings.xml like this:

```
<settings>
...
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>central-proxy</id>
      <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://myrepository/releases</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  ..
</settings>
```

This configuration can either be put in your user settings (${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml) or global settings ({$M2_HOME}/conf/settings.xml).

Answer (score 1):

Set your desired repositories as a mirror of everything else.

More details: http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html